# Firebase 9.0.0 - FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException and reauthenticate(AuthCredential)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase 9.0.0.

If an user want to change the user email or password, Firebase can throw a FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException.

```
firebaseUser.updateEmail(newEmail).addOnCompleteListener(...
```

In the docs, there is stated to call "reauthenticate(AuthCredential)" in this situation.
In the OnCompleteListener I catch the exception but I'm not able to create the EmailAuthCredential.
How is it supposed to do? From where I take the EmailAuthCredential?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this is covered [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user):

> Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user has recently signed in. If you perform one of these actions, and the user signed in too long ago, the action fails and throws FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException. When this happens, re-authenticate the user by getting new sign-in credentials from the user and passing the credentials to reauthenticate. For example:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication. The example below shows
// email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers,
// such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
                // retry changing the password here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with EmailProvider. To reauthenticate, you need credential, and to get credential you need password. I solved it with alert dialog with edit text where user has to enter his password.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String reauthenticatePassword = mEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!reauthenticatePassword.isEmpty()) {
               AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
              .getCredential(firebaseUser.getEmail(),reauthenticatePassword);
               firebaseUser.reauthenticate(credential);
               }
```